# how to format price with currency symbol in HTML5?

Tags: css, html

I have to show price $1.99 like $1<sup>99</sup>, but I want to make sure that Google indexes $1.99 and not $199.

Different variation for i18n/localization.

$1.99 = $1<sup>99</sup>
€1.55 = €1<sup>55</sup>
CAN$2.99 = CAN$2<sup>99</sup>

Thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't exclude the decimal. It's going to screw up more than just Google.

Comment: I am not excluding the decimal, but like to know what else can get screwed up by excluding the decimal.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the decimal point (the period in this case) in a `span` and set it to `display: none`.

Comment: Actually Google punishes for hiding stuff using display: none.

Answer (score 1):

try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d7vMb/2/

html

```
CAN$2.99 = CAN$2.<span>99</span>
```

css

```
span {
    position       : relative;
    left           : -.3em;
    vertical-align : super;   
    padding-bottom : .38em;
    background     : #fff; /* this will cover the dot */
    font-size      : 0.76em;
}
```

I tried to change the font-size from 1 to 20 `em` and it seems correctly working (no unwanted overlaps). In this way you can also avoid `display: none`.